# c programming..difference between counter controlled loop and logic controlled loop

Tags: c, loops, control-flow

I was reading the control flow in C programming it said better to use "while loop" for logic controlled loops and "for loop" for counter controlled loop.

My confusion is that I could not understand the difference between the counter controlled and the logic controlled loops?

Comment: That's a false dichotomy. Either loop kind can implement any kind of logic. Btw, there are 3 loops in C. And you can always implement your own with goto statements.

Comment: @TanveerBadar: if you count the infamous "goto", there are 4 ;) And while you are right, doing what you say is kind of abusive. "for"s are for counting, and "(do)-whiles" are for conditioning.

Comment: @virolino: No, it is not abusive. There are natural uses of `for` for “logic-controlled” loops, such as iterating through a linked list. The service a `for` loop provides is not counting, it is facilitating an initial expression or declaration and/or an update expression. Any loop in which those are beneficial is suitable for a `for` statement.

Comment: @SujayGirl: The source you used for this information may be low quality, in which case you should not rely on it. When you ask questions about statements made somewhere, you should include quotations of the statements and citations of where they appear.

Comment: All loops in C are logic controlled (whatever that means): the value of the expression controlling the loop is evaluated in a logic true or false (or 1 or 0) context.

Answer (score 1):

Write them down:

logic controlled loop:

```
while(condition == true) {
    // do stuff
}
```

counter controlled loop:

```
for(int counter=0; counter<10; counter++) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Don't overthink this: `for` loop if you have something that has to be done for a exact number of times, `while` loop if you want something done while a condition is true.

Answer (score 0):

"Counter controlled" means that you know exactly the number of times the loop has to be executed. The "exactly" is usually given by a variable in the code, or any other expression which evaluates to a number.

**Example**: if you have the data for 10 people, you need to run the loop 10 times in order to make some processing for all people.

---

"Logic controlled" means that you do not know for how many times you need to run the loop, but you know the condition when it must stop executing.

**Example**: you want to make sure that the user provides a valid number for his age, instead of his name. So you will loop reading the age, until the user enters a number, instead of his name. It can be 1 execution (if the user is smart), or it can be many times, if the user is less than smart.

Answer (score 0):

A counter-controlled loop is when you're processing sequential numbers until a known limit. A common example is when you're stepping through all the elements of an array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < array_length; i++) {
    // do something with array[i]
}
```

A logic-controlled loop is when you're repeating until some more general condition changes. For instance, if you're reading a file, you want to read until you reach the end.

```
while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, file)) {
    // do something with buffer
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Logic control loop will be until the logic evaluates to be true. Like the while loop. Before we execute we don't know how many times the loop will execute.
But coming counter control loops we are making the loop to execute fixed number of times. Like the for loop contains initiation testing and increment/decrement. Before we execute we know how many times the loop will execute.